# Dynamic Topic Model Path

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

Thanks for stopping by!  I have a question about the dynamic topic model path:

```html
>>> from gensim.test.utils import common_corpus, common_dictionary
>>> from gensim.models.wrappers import DtmModel
>>>
>>> path_to_dtm_binary = "/path/to/dtm/binary"
>>> model = DtmModel(
...     path_to_dtm_binary, corpus=common_corpus, id2word=common_dictionary,
...     time_slices=[1] * len(common_corpus)
```

what is the path the dynamic topic model binary?  Is that something I need to install or download?  Where can I install or download that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/wrappers/dtmmodel.html), you can go one of two ways:

1. Use precompiled binaries for your OS version from https://github.com/magsilva/dtm/tree/master/bin
2. Compile binaries manually from /blei-lab/dtm (original instruction available in https://github.com/blei-lab/dtm/blob/master/README.md), or use this

```
git clone https://github.com/blei-lab/dtm.git
sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev
cd dtm/dtm
make
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'd like to preface this by saying you are correct.  I am working on a windows server 2012 not on Ubuntu 10.04, OpenSUSE 11.2, or CentOS 5.5 so those precompiled binaries wont work nor will these commands :(